# We found a potential security vulnerability in one of your dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, github

I uploaded my node.js project on github and used mongoDB.
now its showing "1 mongose vulnerability found in package-lock.json "
I tried to fix the issue using "npm audit fix" command
it's showing

**npm WARN contact_list@1.0.0 No repository field.

removed 1 package in 0.767s

2 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

fixed 0 of 0 vulnerabilities in 94 scanned packages**

so where is the problem?

Comment: See which packages have an issue with `npm audit` and check those repositories for clues

Comment: did that too===,getting this message       npm audit security report ===                        

found 0 vulnerabilities
 in 94 scanned packages

Comment: Sorry missed the "0 of 0" there. Did you try removing the package-lock.json and node_modules and running `npm install` to see if that updates and fixes anything?

Comment: yes I did..the problem is in vs code its saying "found  0 vulnerabilities", but in my git repository it's different   **1 mongose vulnerability found in package-lock.json  Remediation
No patched version is available.

Details
CVE-2017-16077
moderate severity
Vulnerable versions: > 0
Patched version: No fix
mongose was a malicious module published with the intent to hijack environment variables. It has been unpublished by npm..**

Answer (score 0):

GitHub and npm and snyk and white source each have their own list of vulnerabilities. Most they have in common, but some are only detected by specific tools. This has been a big frustration of mine

GitHub uses Dependabot to check your dependencies. Fortunately Dependabot can also fix the detected vulnerability for you or tell you exactly what command do execute.